# Spring Security 3 custom authentication by REMOTE_USER

Tags: spring-security

I need to implement custom security scheme using Spring security 3.0.5.

The user must be authenticated automatically (without any login-form) by `REMOTE_USER` field in request. It seems that I must implement custom `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and `AuthenticationManager`.

Am i taking the right direction? What could be the XML configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wanting to accept identity assertions made by some other agent? Fair enough; there are scenarios where that makes sense. However, you *must verify* those assertions; there are many ways to do this, here are some:

- If you share a database with the asserting entity, you can do a check on magic numbers.
- You can use cryptographic signatures
- You can check that the message is coming from a host that is permitted to make such assertions — which should be inside a network that you control and where you control the path in between too, which is fairly easy to do but a critical deployment factor that you need to document.

The simplest method is probably to write your own `AuthenticationProvider`, whose job it is to look at the credentials presented (the `REMOTE_USER` field and who is asserting it in your case) and decide whether to build an `Authentication` object. If not, it should throw an exception. You register your auth provider (assuming it is a bean called `myAuthProvider`) like this:

```xml
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

As I said, you'll need to have an auth provider. If the user name is being supplied through an HTTP header and you're just going to trust it, you're actually in what's called a pre-authenticated case (i.e., there's something else that's done the authentication step for you). The Spring Security documentation has a [whole chapter on this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html) using Siteminder as an example: just change the header name and it should work. (Well, you'll also need a user details service, so that you can map from the authenticated user to the set of authorities that they are granted, but that's a whole 'nother story.)

Comment: Thank You a lot, seems that this pre-authentication scenario is exactly what I need to do. Will try it!

Comment: @never: Glad to be of help. Just be careful though: it's so easy to get security wrong and leave things open by accident (speaking from experience!). You _have_ to test it once deployed, and test with non-authenticated clients too.